# JavaScript, HTML search engine - how to get parent of an element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, searchbar

**My problem is:**

Search script is working, but it only hides h3 elements from the code.

```
<h3 class="post-subtitle" style="display: flex;">Protokoły tunelowania VPN</h3>
<h3 class="post-subtitle" style="display: flex;">Certyfikat cyfrowy</h3>
```

I need the code to hide the whole div with "post" ID instead of just h3 element.

How do i do that?

**HTML Code for Search Bar:**

```
<div id="kontener" class="container">
    <div style="text-align:center" id="search-bar">
      <input type="text" id="searchbar" onkeyup="searchBar()" class="shadow-lg">
    </div>
</div>
```

**HTML Code on Website**

```
<!-- First element -->

<div id="post">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
<div class="post-preview">
<a href="URL">
<h2 class="post-title"><i class="far fa-sticky-note fa-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> ASO</h2>
<h3 class="post-subtitle" style="display: flex;">Protokoły tunelowania VPN</h3>
</a>
<p class="post-meta">11 Maj, 2021</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
</div>

<!-- End of First element -->

<!-- Second element -->

<div id="post">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
<div class="post-preview">
<a href="URL">
<h2 class="post-title"><i class="far fa-sticky-note fa-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i> ELSK</h2>
<h3 class="post-subtitle" style="display: flex;">Certyfikat cyfrowy</h3>
</a>
<p class="post-meta">26 Kwiecień, 2021</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
</div>

<!-- End of Second element -->
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
<script>
function searchBar() {
    let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value
    input=input.toLowerCase();
    let x = document.getElementsByClassName('post-subtitle');
      
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
            x[i].style.display="none";
        }
        else {
            x[i].style.display="flex";                 
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: To answer the question title you may want to look at `element.closest` see the [mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Comment: You cannot have multiple elements with the same `id`. `id`s must be unique.

Comment: `x[i].closest(".row").parentElement.style.display = "none";`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to target couple of parent nodes, either by .parentElement / .parentNode or use .closest function.

Example:

```
<script>
function searchBar() {
    let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value
    input=input.toLowerCase();
    let x = document.getElementsByClassName('post-subtitle');
      
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
            x[i].closest('#post').style.display="none";
            // Or this below (note each parentElement targets parent tag)
            // x[i].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.display="none";
        }
        else {
            x[i].closest('#post').style.display="flex";                 
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Since the OP is using duplicate `id`s, this really isn't correct. You'd probably want `.closest(".row").parentElement`.

Comment: Well this WILL work, and it happens more than you would think due to using some nasty templating engines in different CMS all around the internet. While having multiple ID's in html is not allowed by W3C standard, browsers still work with them as with classes. You are free to test this and report if I'm not right

Comment: Thanks, but I've been coding and teaching HTML, CSS and JavaScript since each was invented, so I know what "works" vs. what's "correct". Just because your code will "work" with bad HTML doesn't make it a "good" or the "correct" way to handle it. I've provided a solution that does not rely on `id`s in the first place, so clearly that would be preferable.

Comment: i didn't mean ID, "post" is the class

Comment: @JSanchoG Your code in your question shows `id`. If it really is a class, then you'd want `x[i].closest(".post").style.display = "none";`